# Upload race condition - Google Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I am attempted to update an avatar on my app and then load and display it once done. However, I am seeing the following errors which seem to indicate a false positive or race condition when the image has actually finished uploading.

I'm using a CicleAvatar widget, but also attempted with NetworkImage and am experiencing the same issues. I have also attempted .then/onComplete and various others outside of a delayed or wrapping it in a completer.

> What is the best way to handle Firebase storage upload and immediate download without error§

Example Error n attempting to retrieve the image from the DownloadURLL:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service
════════════════════════════ HTTP request failed, statusCode: 503,
```

```dart
!isImageProcessing
  ? GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => _uploadAvatarImage(),
    child: CircleAvatar(
      minRadius: 40,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.imageURL),
    ),
  )
  : Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
```

The actual upload of the file is being managed in this function/class

```dart
class StorageController {
  static Future<String> storeAvatarImage(File file) async {
    // Get user UUID to reference avatar;
    String uuid = await identityBloc.retrieveActiveUUID();
    String downloadURL;
    TaskSnapshot ts;
    
    ts = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('avatars/$uuid-avatar.png')
      .putFile(file);
    
    downloadURL = await ts.ref.getDownloadURL();
    
    User user = await ProfileDataController.retrieveUserProfile();
    user.imageURL = downloadURL;
    await ProfileDataController.createUserProfile(user);
    downloadURL = downloadURL;
    
    return downloadURL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not properly awaiting for the file upload. Can you change this line to read:

```
    ts = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('avatars/$uuid-avatar.png')
        .putFile(file);
// removed the below part
//      .snapshot;
```

Comment: Thanks you are right, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The image would update if there are listeners to listen to changes in the changed user avatar.

What I would advise as a workaround is store the avatarUrl to firestore or rtdb, there you can set a listener that updates the UI on the frontend when a change is written there.

Initially, the avatarUrl field would be null then when a user uploads a new picture the field is then a string and you can supply it to your UI

Comment: The downloadURl is working, but tehe 503 occurs when I attempt to load the image.